# Look up specific csv values through jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, csv

Is it possible to use jQuery ajax to look up specific values from a csv file as needed, on say a button click?

For example, say the CSV has the following structure:

```
country, capital, population, currency,
france, paris, 65950000, euro,
italy, rome, 59685227, euro,
```

Could I return only the population count for italy?

I have seen a couple examples where the entire csv file is converted into js arrays before any value is returned, though would prefer avoiding this method if possible as the csv file is likely to be very big.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert entire csv into js arrays:

1. Make a country dropdown in your HTML
2. On button click, pass `POST` parameters such as *country*, *population* to your server-side script (php, asp.net, whatever)

   ```
   data: { country: "italy", find: "population" }
   ```
3. Read csv file on server
4. Find row that contains *italy* as `country` and extract your desired values, for example `population`
5. Only return your desired values back to client and read them in `$.ajax()` response

See **[Examples at the bottom of jQuery ajax page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**

Comment: is their no client side alternative? was hoping the csv file could be accessed in the same way as you would json